# Proving quadratic convergence implies superlinear convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, optimization

if $\lim_{k\to \infty} x^k = x^*$ then the error by our approximation $x^k$ is

$$e_{k} = ||x^{k}-x^*||$$

Quadratic convergence means $$e_{k+1}\le ae_k^2$$

where $a>0$

according to my book. I don't see why this converges. Maybe it should be:

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{e_{k+1}}{e_k^2}\le a$$

for some $a>0$

I must prove that it implies superlinear convergence:

$$\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{e_{k+1}}{e_k}=0$$

I don't see why quadratic implies superlinear. I can see, however, that superlinear implies quadratic, I think. Because $\lim \frac{e_{k+1}}{e_k^2} = \lim \frac{e_{k+1}}{e_k}\frac{1}{e_k}$ which is the limit of something going to $0$ and something bounded.

Where is the error in my argument and how to prove quadratic convergence implies superlinear convergence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $e_k \to 0$. If $(x^k)$ is quadratic convergent, then $e_{k+1} \leqslant ae_k^2$, or 
$$
0 \leqslant \frac {e_{k+1}}{e_k} \leqslant ae_k \to 0 [n\to \infty]. 
$$
Now the conclusion follows the squeezing theorem.